# Control a city state's bonus resources?

Tags: civilization-6

In the city state interface under Suzerain benefits, the last item listed is something like "control the city state's resources". It then lists the resources that the city state has, including bonus resources (e.g wheat and cattle). How does this work? Will extra food or production be distributed amongst my cites? I understand how strategic and luxury resources would work since those operate in a global fashion, but not bonus resources.

Comment: I currently can't confirm this but I strongly believe that they do nothing useful for the suzerain. (But will show up in the resources report)

Comment: @Nijin22 If they don't provide any benefit (or disadvantage) to the Suzerain, I'm not sure why they would even include it in the game.

Comment: @pushasha I think its just one of those minor version 1 bugs that they haven't gotten around to fixing yet

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Clarification: If they were _never intended_ to provide any benefit, I'm not sure why they would have included it in the list of effects.

Comment: I have wondered the same thing. I think the only benefit they offer is when your religion/pantheon has a bonus of some sort - like the Oral Tradition pantheon: http://civ6.gamepedia.com/Religion#Found_Pantheon

Comment: Does the Buenos Aires Suzerain bonus turn them into amenities?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the bonuses from being a Suzerain as listed in the [wiki](http://civ6.gamepedia.com/Suzerain):

> - The city-state follows you into war and peace with other players.
> - Your units may enter city-state lands.
> - Your Builder units may improve city-state tiles.
> - See 3 tiles around the city-state.
> - Can pay Gold to temporarily take control of the city-state's military.
> - Gain ownership of all the city-state's resources.

- Not listed but you are also give their unique bonus for being their Suzerain. All the city states and their unique bonuses are listed -> [here](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/City-state_(Civ6)#List_of_City-States_and_their_Suzerain_bonuses).

You specifically asked about the last one, gaining ownership. This is the same as it was in prior Civ games. **By being the suzerain you get the luxury and strategic resources that they have.** The luxury ones provide amenities (if you don't already have that resource), and strategic ones can be used for the corresponding units.

**In no Civ games including this one do you ever get food/production resources from being the Ally/Suzerain of a city state.** They just list that you control all resources, but the excess bonus resources do not give you anything as they are for providing bonus production/food on specific tiles.